# SSRS writing summary expression

Tags: ssrs-2008, expression

I am using SSRS 2008 and am trying to write a summary expression:

```
=iif(Fields!contact_type.Value = "Face to Face",sum(Fields!duration.Value),0) / 
sum(Fields!duration.Value)
```

But when I view this result in the table, the result is not equal to correct value.  How do I formulate this so that it calculates the total duration for "Face to FAce" records divided by total duration for all records?

I tried this expression now in SSRS 2008 BIDS:

```
=sum(Fields!F2F_duration.Value) / sum(Fields!duration.Value, "NC60percentGrid")
```

where NC60percentGrid is the name of my dataset, but the total is still not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the scope.  See more here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mat_stephen/archive/2005/05/26/405407.aspx

**Edit**

Try moving your IIF inside of the SUM (as opposed to the other way around). Give this a shot:

```
=sum(iif(Fields!contact_type.Value = "Face to Face",Fields!duration.Value),0)) / 
sum(Fields!duration.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks Alison, I just tried this but it is still not correct.  Did I formulate this expression correctly?

Comment: What are the values that SSRS are calculating and what are values that you think you should be seeing?